# Skeptical on my answers to the proves.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

I solved two problems that involve proofs, and so I am a little skeptical if I have done it correctly.

1.) Prove that for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $m$ is even, then $mn$ is even.

-So for this proof, I let m be an integer, then m = 2k, and n = 2p. So then we get mn = 2k(2p) = 4kp = 2(2kp). Which gives us an even integer. The question I have is that if we only asked m to be even, then do I ignore the n, and go ahead do this instead: m = 2k, then mn = 2k(n) = 2kn? Or the way I had it is correct?

2.) Prove there are no integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m^{2} = 4n+3$.

-Here I proved it by contradiction, I assumed m, and n to be integers. Then I simplifying the expression: $m^{2} = 4n+3 \rightarrow n = \frac{m^{2}}{4} - \frac{3}{4}$. But this contradicts our assumption, hence there are no m, and n  integers. Did I correctly proved this prove?

Comment: Hint for the second.  If $m$ is even then what is the remainder of $m^2$ when divided by four?  If $m$ is odd then what is the remainder of $m^2$ when divided by four?  What is the remainder of $4n+3$ when divided by four?

Comment: to your first question: Don't presuppose $n$ is even.  So your question about about "ignoring n"  is better thought of as not assuming n is even, because, perhaps it is odd.  So $mn =   2k(n) = 2(kn), and is therefore even, as it is divisible by 2.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yeah, for the first proof don't want to let $n = 2p$, because we aren't given that $n$ is even. You want to write $mn$ as $2kn$.
- For the second proof, you say, "but this contradicts our assumption." Why does that contradict your assumption? I don't immediately see it. Why can't that numerator $m^2-3$ ever be a multiple of four?

Answer (score 1):

Your skepticism was, unfortunately, valid: You cannot assume that $n$ is even, since that was never stated. It is however enough to assume that only $m$ is even and $n$ an integer, because, as you already outlined, that means that there is an integer $k$ such that $mn=2kn$ and therefore $\frac{mn}2=kn\in\mathbb Z$, (two divides $mn$).

The second proof is also not valid. All you did was rewrite the equation in a way that produces a fraction. However, what if $m^2$ happened to be a number that has remainder three when divided by four? Then, there would be some integer $p\in\mathbb Z$ such that $m^2=4p+3$ and therefore $\frac{m^2}4-\frac34=\frac{4p+3}4-\frac34=p\in\mathbb Z$.

The way I would go about proving the second statement is like this:

$4n+3=2(2n+1)+1$ must be odd, since $2(2n+1)$ is a multiple of 2, and $4n+3$ is one more than that. So, we use proof by contradiction by assuming that $m^2=4n+3$, and therefore $m^2$ is odd just like $4n+3$. Now we check two cases:

1. case: $m$ is even:

If $m$ is even, then $m\cdot m=m^2$ is even as per 1.). Contradiction to $m^2$ is odd!

2. case: $m$ is odd:

If $m$ is odd, then there is some $p\in\mathbb Z$ such that $m=2p+1$. Then, $$m^2=(2p+1)^2=4p^2+4p+1=4(p^2+p)+1.$$ Note that $p^2+p\in\mathbb Z$. But $m^2$ is also equal to $4n+3$. That means $$4n+3=4(p^2+p)+1.$$ That on the other hand means $$3-1=4(p^2+p)-4n,\\2=4(p^2+p-n).$$ Since both sides are multiples of 2, we can divide by 2: $$1=2(p^2+p-n).$$ This is a clear contradiction: 2 is even, so its product with an integer $(p^2+p-n)$ is even (again as per 1.) ), and 1 is not even, so the two sides cannot be equal.

I'm sure you can discard half of this answer and still get a readable proof, but I wanted to make sure you see all the steps that go into it.